How can I give a Linux routing table an alphabetic name?
The ip command only allows numeric table names.  But I see that some default tables exist with alphabetic names (local, main).  Is there a way to give it an alphabetic alias?

Add it to /etc/iproute2/rt_tables for iproute2 and to /etc/systemd/networkd.conf for systemd. (The initial tables are defined in /usr/share/iproute2 for the former, and hardcoded for the latter.)
/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
1      arpanet
2      dn42

# Reserved
253    default
254    main
255    local

/etc/systemd/networkd.conf.d/tables.conf
[Network]
RouteTable=1:arpanet
RouteTable=2:dn42

